# How to select valid SQL Server datatypes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I'm looking for a way to select every valid SQL Server datatypes to load a combobox with that values, but I don't know where I can select it values.

An example for what I want to do is this:

[image]

Img Link: http://puu.sh/m4VpV/65bcb8dca6.png

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can look at the sys.types view. But be warned it will return ALL the datatypes including those that are deprecated (ie. text) and others that really shouldn't be used (timestamp, sql_variant). There is no automatic way to create nvarchar(32) and nvarchar(max).

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`SYS.TYPES`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188021.aspx) system view

```
select name 
from sys.types
where is_user_defined = 0 -- SQL Server system data type.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was what I wanted.

:)